# How to reduce bubble-notification time in empathy?

Tags: 10.04, empathy

empathy shows a bubble notification message on top right corner if a user comes online or goes offline (obviously we can change them from the preferences), but is there any way we can reduce the time for which the bubble notification remains on screen.
By default it remains fro 3-4 seconds, is there any way we can change it to 1 or may be 2 seconds (I know the matter is of few seconds only but 4 seconds looks too long and I want to reduce it).
Any help is welcome.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if Empathy uses the NotifyOSD bubbles (I don't use Empathy), but if it does, maybe this can help:

First install patched NotifyOSD:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:leolik/leolik; 
sudo apt-get update;
sudo apt-get upgrade;
sudo apt-get install libnotify-bin;
pkill notify-osd;
```

Then install NotifyOSDconfig:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8;
sudo apt-get update;
sudo apt-get install notifyosdconfig;
```

Run NotifyOSD from launcher or menu and configure your bubbles.

All this from here: http://www.webupd8.org/2010/05/finally-easy-way-to-customize-notify.html